# Easier JavaScript method names with destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to find a way so that I can remove the repetitive need for having to use the object name and just the keys. For example:

```
function(teams) {
    return {
        teamName: teams.name,
        teamCity: teams.city,
        teamState: teams.state,
        teamMascot: teams.mascot
    }
}
```

It would be nice so that I can have it so that the need to re-use teams each time can be eliminated. Any help would be great.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's wrong with using the original object with property names like `name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already mentioned the solution in your title. Just use [destructuring.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
function logTeam(teams) {
  let { name, city, state, mascot } = teams;
  console.log({
    teamName: name,
    teamCity: city,
    teamState: state,
    teamMascot: mascot
  });
}

logTeam({
  name: 'SO Silverhawks',
  city: 'Interwebs',
  state: 'Earth',
  mascot: 'Stacky'
});
```

If you want to avoid using the names at all but your properties follow a predictable pattern, you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and work with the keys directly.

```js
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
  return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function createTeam(teams) {
  let result = {};
  Object.keys(teams).forEach(key => {
    result[`team${capitalizeFirstLetter(key)}`] = teams[key];
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(createTeam({
  name: 'SO Silverhawks',
  city: 'Interwebs',
  state: 'Earth',
  mascot: 'Stacky'
}));
```

[`capitalizeFirstLetter` source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/how-do-i-make-the-first-letter-of-a-string-uppercase-in-javascript)

Comment: What about if I have lots of keys? Do I have to add all of them? Tried to use `...rest` but did not work the way I tried.

Comment: Which eliminates the need to dereference teams over and over, but now each field name must be referenced twice, so I'm not sure this really gains anything, personally.

Comment: @pertrai1 Yes, if that's how you want to do it. If the properties you're assigning to will always be `team${TitleCaseObjectKey}` then there's a solution for that as well.

Comment: @MikeC Yes it would be great to do it in a way where I don't have to list every one of them as there are close to 20 keys. They don't all start the same so I can't use the option you showed. So should `let { name, city, state, mascot, ...more} = teams` work or am I doing that wrong?

Comment: @MikeC I was told it is best to factor out the object into a variable so it does not have to be duplicated so much but that does not click for me.

Comment: @pertrai1 You're doing that wrong. The rest/spread operator (`...more`) is for arrays. Theoretically, doing `let { name, city, ...more } = teams` would put the remaining keys into an array named `more`. You can't dynamically create variables in the current scope without some serious bad idea tom-foolery.

Comment: @pertrai1 Extracting properties from an object into a variable is only really a good idea if you're planning to reference that same property multiple times. Every time you grab a property from an object, some kind of lookup occurs. The engine can optimize this in some cases but it can't in the general case. It can be helpful for reading comprehension to separate them out but that's a judgement call based on the context of the function and how many variables you're generating.

Comment: @MikeC Thank you so much for the help and explanations

Comment: @pertrai1 Any time. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function (teams) {
    const {name, city, state, mascot} = teams;
    return {
        teamName: team,
        teamCity: city,
        teamState: state,
        teamMascot: mascot
    }
}
```

Comment: But why would you not destructure directly in the parameter list?

Comment: @torazaburo It was just the first approach which came to my mind, anyway there are some better answers than mine. :)

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward approach, given the inability to destructure into objects, is:

```
const getTeamData = 
  ({name: teamName, city: teamCity, state: teamState, mascot: teamMascot}) =>
    ({teamName, teamCity, teamState, teamMascot});
```

[Various approaches](https://github.com/rtm/js-pick-notation) have been suggested for destructuring into objects, which would allow the following kind of syntax:

```
function getTeamData(team) {
  return team.{name: teamName, city: teamCity, state: teamState, mascot: teamMascot};
}
```

or

```
function getTeamData(team) {
  return { {name: teamName, city: teamCity, state: teamState, mascot: teamMascot} = team };
}
```

But the powers that be on TC39 have shown no interest in such alternatives.

#### Proxies

Alternatively, since all you seem to want to be doing is to access the `name` field as `teamName`, consider using a proxy:

```
function getTeamData(team) {
  return new Proxy(team, {
    get(target, prop) { return target[`team${capitalize(prop)}`]; }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have an object with many properties, you can use this function that loops over them:

```js
function prefix(obj, prefix) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce( (o, k) => 
        Object.assign(o, { [prefix+k.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+k.substr(1)]: obj[k]} ),
        {} );
}

var result = prefix({
    name: '49ers',
    city: 'San Francisco',
    state: 'California',
    mascot: 'Sourdough Sam'
}, 'team');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: With all due respect, this seems like a complicated solution to a problem which doesn't exist.

Comment: It is just an answer to address an apparent need the OP expressed in a comment to another answer: *"What about if I have lots of keys? Do I have to add all of them?"*. But I like how you have approached it in your answer.

Comment: Or `return Object.assign({}, ...Object.keys(obj).map(k => ({[prefix+k.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+k.substr(1)]: obj[k]}));`.